# Return json text via Kestrel MVC Server

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, kestrel-http-server

Consider the following class:

```cs
    class Fake
    {
        public int test { get; set; }
    }
```

and now my `GET`:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Produces(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    var fake = new Fake { test = 1 };
    return Ok(fake);
}
```

Result = a perfect:

```json
{
   "test": 1
}
```

This is my expected result - the following are all my alternate failures:

So, what I want to do is *not* use the class, but the underlying `JSON` representation of it, so I tried:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Produces(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    var fake = "{ \"test\": 1 }";
    return Ok(fake);
}
```

That yields me:

```json
"{ \"test\": 1 }"
```

Which is obviously not what I want.

The so I found another 'answer' on Stack Overflow that lead to me try:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Produces(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    var fake = "{ \"test\": 1 }";
    return Ok(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(fake));
}
```

Which then yields:

```json
{"test":[]}
```

My final attempt was

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Produces(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    var fake = "{ \"test\": 1 }";
    return new JsonResult(fake);
}
```

Which gets me:

```json
"{ \u0022test\u0022: 1 }"
```

How the heck do I get my method to return the `JSON` I get in the first call, but using the `JSON` string I'm actually going to be returning?

And why did the second attempt get me that weird `JSON` result?

Comment: What happens with _var fake = @"{""test"": 1 }";_

Comment: @Steve: No difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your string object will be encoded by serializer leading to the double encoded string, use `Content`:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Produces(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    var fake = "{ \"test\": 1 }";
    return Content(fake);
}
```

P.S.

For your deserialization-serialization approach you can try using the System.Text.Json serializer - default for ASP.NET Core since the 3rd version:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Produces(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    var fake = "{ \"test\": 1 }";
    return Ok(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<object>(fake));
}
```

Comment: You are a star! Thank you SO much. The answer I was looking for was your second one because that not only returns the JSON but also maintains the application/json content type!

Comment: @RachelAmbler was glad to help! `Content` allows specifying content type if one determined automatically is not suitable - `return Content("...", "application/json")`.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks again. You've fixed the last piece in an 8 week jigsaw puzzle. You've no idea how happy I am right now!